# Is there a way to show a React Component code into a <code> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm building a tester page where the user sees a library component and documents its use.

Here is the component:

```
render = () => {
    let component = (
            <Slider
                onSlide={this.handleSlide}
                totalCount={120}
            />
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Slider Test:</h2>
            {component}

            <code>HOW TO PRINT COMPONENT CODE HERE?</code>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I want to show the component in use and at the end the code I've used to test it.

How can I put on screen the component code without the need to replicate it inside the  tag?

Is there a way to do it directly or though an existing npm library?

Answer (score 0):

You could escape the code and it should appear correctly.

You can use that library to do it [escape-html npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escape-html)

You should also be able to find specialized libraries to do it like this one [react code view npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-code-view)